# arm instruction ldr error on gcc works fine on armcc

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, armcc

```
LDR     r2, =0x0 :OR: (Region_64K << 1) :OR: Region_Enable
```

What does the above command do ?
on `armcc` it compiles fine while with `arm-none-eabi-gcc` it gives an error

> garbage following instruction -- `ldr
>   r2,=0x0:OR:(Region_64K<<1):OR:Region_Enable'

where on gcc

```
Region_Enable = 0b1
Region_64K   = 0b01111
```

on armcc

```
Region_Enable EQU 2_1
Region_64K   EQU 2_01111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's armasm's [syntax for bitwise operators](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731181912.html) in expressions. For the GNU assembler, you'll want `|` instead of `:OR:`.

Since armasm claims that using `|` as an alias is deprecated for some reason (although `&` for `:AND:` and `^` for `:EOR:` are apparently fine), you may need to resort to some preprocessor magic if you want to maintain compatibility with both toolchains.